# SCALA : Use Cases for extracting particular values from Array

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark

```
 var word_count = rdd.flatMap(lines=>lines.split(",").map(words=>(words,1)).reduceByKey(_+_).collect
word_count:Array[(String,Int)] = Array((Ankita,1),(shelly,1),(A,2),(B,1))
```

//Now writing the below query results in an empty string but I want to extract (A,2) and (B,1) .

```
var filtered = word_count.filter(values=>(values=="A") || (values=="B")).collect 
filtered:Array[(String,Int)] = Array()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
word_count.filter(x => (x._1 == "A") || (x._1 == "B"))
```

or

```
word_count.filter(x => Seq("A", "B").contains(x._1))
```

Your code compares `Tuple2` with `String` giving trivially false expression:

```
scala> ("A", 1) == "A"
<console>:24: warning: comparing values of types (String, Int) and String using `==' will always yield false
       ("A", 1) == "A"
            ^
res0: Boolean = false
```